# Using LSTM to forecast vehicle position - multivariate time series - Matlab

Tags: time-series, lstm, matlab

I am trying to train an LSTM model on Matlab to forecast the position of a vehicle when driving around a roundabout. My main concern right now is that my dataset consists of 4 features (X position, Y position and 2 other) and I referred to [Are RNN or LSTM appropriate Neural Networks approaches for multivariate time-series regression?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/43938/are-rnn-or-lstm-appropriate-neural-networks-approaches-for-multivariate-time-ser?newreg=53c517416a054d36893a95a45a39a11a)

and understood the method of sliding for multistep predictions, although intuitively this seems like the right way to do it, my model generates huge errors for some reason - prediction of tn is fairly alright but tn+1 onwards there is an issue similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52778922/stock-prediction-gru-model-predicting-same-given-values-instead-of-future-stoc/52786399?noredirect=1#comment93125020_52786399).

Additionally, I have about 200 samples in my dataset ( i.e driving path of 200 different vehicles in the roundabout) how do I go about training a model for all these time-series patterns?

As of now, I am trying to make a model to work on 1 time-series sample and later build on it.

Any suggestion and proposals are appreciated!